# Excel Sheet Tab Tooltip

Tags: excel, tooltip

I am wondering if there are any vba codes or something to show a tooltips in excel's sheet tabs.
Since I'm working on a Excel WorkBook with many sheets, I would like to obtain a small description of each sheet just hovering with mouse over the sheet tab.

I don't know whether this is possible

Comment: Why not name the sheets with a descriptive name?